# Popup window Reveal plugin wont popup on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, widget

Hello I am using Reveal popup plugin combined with cookies to show popup only once a day.
This is my code

```
<head>
..
<script type="text/javascript">
        function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var c_value = document.cookie;
            var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
            if (c_start == -1) {
                c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
            }
            if (c_start == -1) {
                c_value = null;
            }
            else {
                c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
                var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) {
                    c_end = c_value.length;
                }
                c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
            }
            return c_value;
        }

        function showModal() {
            // Check if cookie existes
            var expireDate = getCookie("showpopup");
            var today = new Date().toUTCString();

            if (expireDate != null && expireDate > today) {
                //Do nothing!
            }
            else {
                //ShowPopup here!
                $('a.reveal-link').trigger('click');

                //Create cookie
                setCookie("showpopup", "anything", 1);
            }
        }        
    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="showModal()">
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" class="reveal-link">Click Me For A Modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
     <h1>Modal Title</h1>
     <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
...other code
</body>
```

So basicaly on page load, the cookie is created but no popup shows. When I manualy click on link "Click Me For A Modal", window is shown so there is no problem with window. When I tried javascript alert message that worked.
The important part of code is:

```
 //ShowPopup here!
                $('a.reveal-link').trigger('click');
```

I have tried diffrent variations for start the script like `$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');` or  `$('#myModal').reveal();` but nothing worked.
Can you help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found it. The problem just occur on my page due more jquery libraries in conflict.